# DataSnap - Different authentication for each server class

Tags: rest, delphi, basic-authentication, datasnap

I have a DataSnap server (Delphi) which currently has one server class, with HTTP Basic Authentication implemented via the TDSAuthenticationManager.OnUserAuthenticate event.  What I want to do next is add a second server class, but the methods in this one will not require any authentication.  I can't see how I can link the new server class to a different authentication manager, without running it on a separate TDSServer component.  So my question is how can I write code in the TDSAuthenticationManager.OnUserAuthenticate event to check which server class is being invoked?  Is there maybe a data item in TDSSession that I can examine?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Don't use the onAuthenticate or onAuthorise events! Let them return True, and then add to each ServerMethodsUnit your own ValidateLogin (or similar name) method that you call independently from the client after the connection has been established. I have a Server with 5 ServerMethodsUnits that connect to different databases - and they each have their own ValidLogin method for different clients.